# Как настроить push уведомление Laravel 9 + Vue 3 + MySql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, nativescript

На данный момент хочу сделать отправку уведомлений с сервера в vue-приложение. Необходимо за 3-2 дня до, допустим,дня рождения пользователя, информировать о скидке. Можно ли каким-то образом индивидуально создавать под каждого пользователя уведомление и также вызывать по расчетам до определенного дня.

Насколько я понимаю, для этого необходимо использовать Notifications в laravel, а затем в очереди отправлять эти уведомления. Но также я сомневаюсь, что может стоит использовать слушатели-события в laravel и производить данные манипуляции там. Или использовать все вместе.
Так как я только начала изучать php и в частности laravel буду рада любой помощи в подсказке какого-либо паттерна действий при данной разработке задачи.

Comment: На стороне MySQL создайте таблицу, в которую записывайте кандидатов на уведомление, и Event Procedure, которая в полночь (ну или в период минимальной загрузки сервера) выгребает из БД таких кандидатов и пишет в эту таблицу (и чистит её от необработанных старых записей).

На стороне Laravel создайте процедуру, которая обращается к этой таблице, и при наличии там записей - отсылает уведомления через Notifications и удаляет те записи, по которым уведомление отправлено. Эту процедуру запускайте по крону или, если имеется, встроенному планировщику.

Comment: @Akina, благодарю за совет, буду пробовать разбираться с данным алгоритмом.

Comment: @Akina _и удаляет те записи, по которым уведомление отправлено._  обычно для уведомлений добавляют статус (прочитано, не прочитано) и висит оно, пока не прочитают, поэтому удалять после отправки не камильфо

Comment: @InDevX Возможно... хотя, как по мне, вот всё это должно быть уже не в списке тех, кого надо оповестить (компактная таблица, в пределе вообще из одного поля - идентификатора юзера), а в таблице отправленных уведомлений.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения я бы использовал очереди, настроить их очень легко посмотрите видео.

Кратко: измените конфигурационные файлы Laravel, создадите таблицы jobs, failed_jobs, далее нужно создать Job (App/Jobs) который будет выполняться (dispatch), я бы рекомендовал отправлять в Job не объекты (к прим. User) а их id.

А так же если дата дня рождения изменилась вам нужно ещё раз добавить задачу в очередь, для проверки изменилась ли она - так же отправляйте её в Job

```
class AlertBirthdaySale implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user_id;
    protected $birthday;
    protected $sale;

    public function __construct($user_id, $birthday, $sale)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->birthday = $birthday;
        $this->sale = $sale;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $user = User::where(['id' => $this->user_id, 'birthday' => $this->birthday])->first();
        if ($user) {
            // Send notification
            SendNotification("Hello user, for your birthday sale is " . $this->sale . "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А запуск этих очередей необходимо осуществлять через расписание?

Comment: @SummerKnight для теста на локалке можно запустить "php artisan queue:listen" а так, вам нужно настроить демона на вашем сервере, либо да, через планировщик https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, буду пробовать решить вопрос данным образом